# JSON deserialization: input DateTime? to output Option<DateTime>

Tags: c#, json, f#, option-type

Context:

one type has two representations: one in C# and one in F#. Value of the C# type gets serialized to json and then deserialized into a value of the F# type.

Is there a straightforward way to convert `null` json properties to `Option<>` F# values?

I'm facing a situation where `null` C# `DateTime? UpdatedDate` property gets serialized to json and then is expected to be deserialized into an `FSharpOption<DateTime> UpdatedDate` value (F# type, C# code, long story...) which breaks the code.

My json looks like this:

```json
{
  "Property1": "1",
  "UpdatedDate": null,
  "Property2": "2"
}
```

I technically could deserialize my json to the C# type containing `DateTime? UpdatedDate` and then map the resulting value to the F# type containing `FSharpOption<DateTime> UpdatedDate`, but surely there must be a better way...

---

EDIT:

To deserialize json I'm using Newtonsoft's `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and .NET 5 + C# 9.

Comment: Which JSON serialization library are you using? If Newtonsoft, then Newtonsoft.Json.FSharp provides support for what you're describing.

Comment: @brianberns Ah, should have mentioned, sorry. I'm using Newtonsoft's `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

Comment: https://github.com/jet/FsCodec has an `FsCodec.NewtonsoftJson` that contains, among others, an `OptionConverter` for Newtonsoft that handles `FSharpOption`s cleanly

For STJ, v5 handles them correctly OOTB

(Formerly `FsCodec.SystemTextJson` had a `JsonOptionConverter` which works universally without requiring the hoops you’re jumping through (but just use the STJ 5.0 libraries is the real answer))

Comment: Thanks @RubenBartelink I'll make sure to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out thanks to the example @brianberns shared. Sample code:

```cs
public class DummyJsonConverter : JsonConverter<FSharpOption<DateTime>>
{
    public override FSharpOption<DateTime> Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        FSharpOption<DateTime>.None;

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        FSharpOption<DateTime> dateTimeValue,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteStringValue("");
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();

serializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DummyJsonConverter());

var whoisResponses = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SharedSupport.Models.Whois.WhoisResponseV2[]>(
    snsMessage.Message,
    serializerOptions);
```

The only caveat is that I replaced the Newtonsoft serializer with the `System.Text.Json` serializer (`JsonSerializer`).

---

EDIT:

Following @ruben-bartelink's advice, I used the proposed nuget (`FsCodec.NewtonsoftJson`) instead of my own custom converter. The code is much simpler now that I don't have to worry about writing my own conversion. Additionally, I don't have to switch to `System.Text.Json`.

```cs
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new OptionConverter());

var whoisResponses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SharedSupport.Models.Whois.WhoisResponseV2[]>(
    snsMessage.Message,
    jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Comment: as per comment on question, if you're switching to STJ, then V5 should Just Work for FSharpOption

Comment: you can also do the above using [`var FsCodec.NewtonsoftJson.Serdes.Deserialize<SharedSupport.Models.Whois.WhoisResponseV2[]>(snsMessage.Message)`](https://github.com/jet/FsCodec/blob/master/src/FsCodec.NewtonsoftJson/Serdes.fs#L33) see https://github.com/jet/FsCodec#serdes - (that allows allows you to switch to STJ by changing the namespace bit in the future)

Answer (score 2):

`OptionConverter` in the [Newtonsoft.Json.FSharp](https://github.com/haf/Newtonsoft.Json.FSharp) package can handle this for you. Your code will look something like this:

```ml
let records =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType[]>(
       json,
       [| OptionConverter() :> JsonConverter |])
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I want to still deserialize in C#, but using the F# type, but I can see a similar rule applies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0). I think I can take it from here, thanks!